# In guava, what is the difference (if any) between Lists.newArrayList() and e.g. Ints.asList() for primitive types

Tags: java, guava

I have always been using guava's [collection utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Lists) to create a list:

```
List<Integer> foo = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3);
```

Lately I found the [primitives utilities](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PrimitivesExplained), which allows this:

```
List<Integer> bar = Ints.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

From [the](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList(E...)) [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)), both `foo` and `bar` are mutable:

```
foo.set(0, 100);
bar.set(0, 100);
```

So what is the difference (if any) between the two, for primitive types like int?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primitives don't work with generics. This

```
List<Integer> foo = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3);
```

would incur the cost of boxing each `int` value and wrapping the whole thing in an `Integer[]` to be passed to `newArrayList`. The `List` returned is not fixed size.

This

```
List<Integer> bar = Ints.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

would only incur the cost of wrapping the three arguments in an `int[]` as that's the parameter type. The `List` returned is fixed size

Comment: It's best to think of `Ints.asList` et al. as equivalents to `Arrays.asList` that work on primitive arrays (since `Arrays.asList` does not do what you probably want with them).